# Two-Column Newspaper Layout with CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid, newspaper3k

I've got CSS grid to produce a two-column layout. But the problem is that it's not top-aligning content in each column.

For example, in the second column, the last element should top-align to but up against the other column-two element.

```css
body>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  /* https://codepen.io/maddesigns/pen/oZGWRN */
  /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow */
}

body>div>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 300px;
}

body>div>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 100px;
}

body>div>div:nth-of-type(3) {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <div style="background:red">
    1
  </div>
  <div style="background:green;">
    2
  </div>
  <div style="background:yellow">
    3
  </div>
  <div style="background:pink">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't use flex for this layout because I wanted to achieve this layout without defining the container height. `column-count:2` *would* have worked without defining the container height but then I couldn't use div reordering.

So I'm using CSS grid because div reordering is still available (e.g./i.e. `order:–1;` works well) and it auto-divies up what to put in each of the two columns.

Comment: See here: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-grid-magazine-layout-in-just-20-lines-of-css - For an alternative solution, without CSS Grid, see here: https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns

Answer (score 1):

The gird is acting exactly as intended, to keep order and symmetry just like this.  I can recommend using 2 grids side by side to achieve what you're looking for.  Here's an example that I made to demonstrate this:

```css
.left{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  /* https://codepen.io/maddesigns/pen/oZGWRN */
  /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow */
}

.right{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
   width: 50%;
  /* https://codepen.io/maddesigns/pen/oZGWRN */
  /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow */
}

.left>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 300px;
}

.left>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 100px;
}

.right>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 200px;
}

.right>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left" style="">
  <div style="background:red">
    1
  </div>
  <div style="background:green;">
    2
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="right">
  <div style="background:yellow">
    3
  </div>
  <div style="background:pink">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This looks great. Sadly this won't let me reorder items between left and right. I'll need JavaScript to move 3 to position 1, for example.

Answer (score 0):

> In fact, until a CSS technology arrives with the ability to automatically close the gaps, **CSS in general has no solution**. Something like this would probably require reflowing the document, so I'm not sure how useful or efficient it would be.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200955/1625909